# Tokenizing binary input

Tags: tokenize, binary-data, idris

The lexers in `base`'s [`Text.Lexer`](https://www.idris-lang.org/docs/current/contrib_doc/docs/Text.Lexer.html) all operate on character inputs, and the token constructors are passed `String` arguments:

```
TokenMap : (tokenType : Type) -> Type
TokenMap tokenType = List (Lexer, String -> tokenType)
```

What is the intended way of tokenizing binary data, i.e. input of type `List Bits8` instead of `String`? Is there anything better than casting each `Bits8` into a `Char` and then casting them back to `Bits8` in the recognizers and the token constructors?